# Prerender nested sequence

Tags: after-effects, premiere

I have added an after effects project to my timeline, and that takes a lot of cpu resource to render.

What I want to do is to prerender only the nested subsequence containing that AE composition to aid the renderer in premiere, but that seems to be ignored, it still plays awfully slow.

Why?

I do not want a solution where I save the background to a video file manually because that will obviously affect the quality of the final video rendering.

## Details

[image: animated background]

This is the particle background that I created in AE with the aid of the tutorial on

.

So I created a nested sequence of it and prerendered that one (selecting the clip and in the menu use sequence->render selection.

[image: sub sequence with green bar]

After half an hour, the three minute long clip has been rendered as you see above and the red bar at the top has turned green.

It also plays nicely.

[image: parent clip]

The parent clip as you see shows that bar in red.

[image: me and the background]

When I try to play the video in premiere, it seems like it does not make use of that prerendition of the nested sequence because it is awfully slow playback.

What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You might be doing nothing wrong.

I find dynamic linking between Premiere and After Effects still slow and buggy in CC2020.

If I have a complex comp in AE, I would pre-render in AE, not using the pre-render function in the Compositions menu (because that seems to irreprably delete the original comp, unless anyone else knows otherwise?), but by exporting the comp as a ProRes file.

Then you have two choices:

1. If you trust dynamic linking:
   Place your pre-render video above everything else in your comp in AE, and see if it beahves better in Premiere.
2. If you don't trust dynamic linking:
   Bring your pre-rendered ProRes .mov file into Premiere, where it will play quickly, and disable your dynamically linked comp.

Comment: I'd be interested to know if others share this viewpoint - maybe I'm doing it all wrong...

Comment: Just relinking a load of after effects comps that became mysteriously unlinked in my latest project. It's buggy as hell.